# Is there a way to get raw message from MassTransit?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a consumer with generic argument `IEvent`. This type is a base interface for all messages, and child interfaces of `IEvent` have some other properties. I'd like to have access to the raw message with all properties of nested types instead of  only `IEvent` scope. These properties can be seen through RMQ admin dashboard and I think there should be a way to put them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `context.TryGetMessage<T>()` to request the specific type, which essentially attempts to deserialize the message into the specified type (as long as it is in the list of messageTypes serialized into the header).

Otherwise, you can use `context.TryGetMessage<JToken>()`, and get the `JToken` from JSON.NET, which can be used to navigate the message body.

Honestly, this isn't the best approach to properly handling events, etc., so I'd refer to the documentation to see how to properly consume the various message types (and let MassTransit do the hard work).

Comment: Thanks, Chris! It is exactly what I need.

Comment: I agree that it is not the best solution, but in my particular case this is the only one, I guess. Long story short, It is for ability to resend messages from their storage, where they are getting into by base interface type. And I need whole raw message to be stored to be able to resend it.

Comment: You could also use the receive context off the consume context to get the body stream.