# MassTransit Kafka Rider get raw message

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

I need to get raw message that was sent to kafka for logging.
For example, if validation context.Message was failed.

I tried answer from this [Is there a way to get raw message from MassTransit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773174/is-there-a-way-to-get-raw-message-from-masstransit), but it doesn't work and `context.TryGetMessage<JToken>()` return null all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Confluent.Kafka` client does not expose the raw message data, only the deserialized message type. Therefore, MassTransit does not have a message body accessible.