# How to get generic message as json from MassTransit Fault event

Tags: masstransit

I have a microservices based application and wish to create a service that captures all Fault events with their message payloads (as json) and stores them in a database for later analysis and potential resubmission. I have created a Fault consumer and can capture the Fault but am unable to generically extract the message payload as json.

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Fault> context)
{
    if (context is PipeContext pipeContext)
    {
        var result = pipeContext.TryGetPayload(out ConsumeContext<Fault> payload2);
        var serCont = context.SerializerContext;
        
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"A message faulted:{context.Message.FaultedMessageId} " +
                       $"{context.Message.Exceptions} " +
                       $"{context.ConversationId}"
    );
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I can see the full details I want in the context.SerializerContext._message but this is unaccessable.
[context.SerializerContext._message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBntx.png)
I saw you comment for a similar question:

> If you did want to later get the actual fault message, you could use
> consumeContext.TryGetMessage<Fault>(out var faultContext) and if it
> was present you'd get it back.

I don't have "T" from every service and therefore want to handle all Faults a JSON.
Is there a way I can capture the full Fault with the message, ideally as json, without having access to every T across my system?
I am on MassTransit 8.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have the message type (`T`), you can use `TryGetMessage<Fault<T>>` and it will return the message type deserialized.

If you don't, or if you want to deal with the JSON in a message directly, using V8 you can get the actual `JsonElement` from the deserializer and navigate the JSON yourself:

`var jsonElement = context.TryGetMessage<JsonElement>()`

Previous answer, but for Newtonsoft: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46779547/1882